# Using SVG images with graceful degradation

Tags: svg

I am trying to use an SVG form an image on a website as it's far more crisper than an PNG/GIF or JPG that I can use. Thing is I want to make sure that older browsers can also see this image (based on this: http://caniuse.com/svg) so is there a standard way to degrade gracefully with SVG images back to PNG/GIF or JPG?

Comment: See [this article on CSS Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/svg-fallbacks/) for one effective technique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By "older browsers", you mean IE. Or at least until IE9 caught up with the rest of the world in SVG support for the first time in over a decade.

Check to see what IE does with the SVG element and namespace. iirc, it just ignored anything related to SVG and you can use conditional comments to fix IE and fall back to using an image in its stead.

```
**SVG stuff here ignored by IE<9**
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <img src="">
    <![endif]-->
```

Comment: Hi Rob, thank you for the response. With your approach I would have to use have this conditional comment for every instance where I insert an SVG file won't it?

Comment: @jaslr - That would be correct and the only other way I can think around that would be to have javascript test for IE and insert that.